# Mongodb authentication with trust mode fails in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

I have a Mongodb server running on localhost, with no authentication (testing purposes). In my Java project, I have added an authentication field to it (so that the user can modify a config, and if it's on trust mode simply leave it blank). The problem is, it gets rejected, and in Mongodb, I get:

> Sat Sep 07 15:04:17.018 [conn4] field missing/wrong type in received authenticat
>   e command testdb

I know why this is happening, but I cannot think of a way to prevent it. The reason it's happening is because db.authenticate() returns false if the authorization fails OR if authentiation test has already succeeded with different credentials. In the mongodb console, I get this right before the error above:

> Sat Sep 07 15:04:17.010 [initandlisten] connection accepted from
>   127.0.0.1:53602  #4 (2 connections now open)

One of the connections would be my shell, and the other is the project. Here's my Java code:

```js
boolean auth =
db.authenticate(getConfig().getString("Database.username", ""),
getConfig().getString("Database.password", "").toCharArray());
        if (!db.isAuthenticated() && auth == false) {
                // Stop the application
        }
```

I must stop it to prevent the console from getting ugly. I don't understand why:

```js
!db.isAuthenticated()
```

Doesn't work. That should have stopped it from disabling. If anyone can help, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by replacing these in my application properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=
```

With:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test
```